# Delete records from "Document No_" to "Document No_" from table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to delete records from a table in SQL Server.

How to delete only records from `Document No_` to `Document No_`? What should be the code?

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE Document No_ .............?
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server:

```
DELETE FROM table_name where DocumentNo_ between No1 and No2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL will something like this, for example to delete records with a DocumentNo_ between 1 and 10:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE documentNo_ BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `BETWEEN` with `DELETE`

this is the query:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE Document_NO BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution - the query I've used is:

```
 DELETE FROM [table_name] WHERE [No_] >= '100' AND [No_] <= '1000'
```

Comment: Is your No_ column a varchar?  Because in that case '999' is not between '100' and '1000'.